# Doubt using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I wanted to evaluate, using residue theorem:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(mx)}{x^2+1}
\end{align*}

Then I use the semicircumference $(C_R)$ of radius $R>2$ and center in $0$ and $f(z)=\dfrac{e^{i(mz)}}{z^2+1}$ because it only has a singularity in $C_R$ $(i)$ and $\Re(f)= \dfrac{\cos{mz}}{z^2+1}$. Then I get:
\begin{align*}
 \oint_{C_R} f(z)dz = \int_{[-R,R]} f(z)dz + \int_{γ_R} f(z)dz $
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 Res(f,i) = \lim_{z\to i} \frac{e^{i(mz)}}{z+i} = \frac{e^{-m}}{2i} = -\frac{i}{2e^m} 
\end{align*}
Hence:

\begin{align*}\oint_{C_R} f(z)dz = 2\pi i (-\frac{i}{2 e^m}) = \frac{\pi}{e^m}\end{align*}

Moreover:

\begin{align*} \left|\int_{γ_R} f(z)dz\right| & \leq \int_{γ_R} \frac{|e^{i(mz)}|}{|z^2+1|} dz \leq 
 \int_{γ_R} \frac{|e^{i(x+iy)}|}{|z^2|-1} dz = \int_{γ_R} \frac{|e^{i(x+iy)}|}{|z^2|-1} dz = \int_{γ_R} \frac{|e^{-y+ix}|}{R^2-1} dz\\
 & = \int_{γ_R} \frac{e^{-y}}{R^2-1} dz \leq \int_{γ_R} \frac{1}{R^2-1} dz
 \leq \frac{\pi R}{R^2-1} \xrightarrow{R\to\infty} 0
\end{align*}

And supposedly I win. But, my question is: Why cannot I use $f(z)=\dfrac{\cos{mz}}{z^2+1}$ and do the same reasoning?

Comment: using $\cos$ directly you will get into troubles into finding a suitable contour of integration. the half circle won't do it..

Comment: @tired Sorry, man, I don't understand why I get into troubles with the half circle .

Comment: how does $\cos(m z)$ behaves along the imaginary axis?

Comment: @tired I feel like 5 years old now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\cos(mz)$ does not fullfill Jordan's lemma on the upper half plane, while $e^{miz}$ (assuming $m>0$) does, so it is better to tackle the problem this way:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(mz)}{z^2+1}\,dz = \text{Re}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{miz}}{z^2+1}\,dz = \text{Re}\left(2\pi i\, \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{miz}}{z^2+1},z=i\right)\right)\tag{1} $$
and since $z=i$ is a simple pole for $\frac{e^{miz}}{z^2+1}$, the residue equals $\frac{e^{-m}}{2i}$ and the integral equals $\color{red}{\large\frac{\pi}{e^m}}$.